# Creating time-varying covariates when time is different for each observation

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis

I'm attempting to conduct survival analysis with time-varying covariates. The data comes from a longitudinal survey that is administered biannually, and currently looks something like this:

```
id  event1yr    event2yr    income 14   income16    income18    income20
1   2014        2020        8            10         13          8       
2   2018        NA          13           15         24          35
```

In the case of my study, I am trying to begin time (t_0) at event1yr, and measure time from that variable, which obviously is different for each observation. So, for instance, time to event for observation 1 is 6 years, whereas the time to event for observation 2 is right-censored and 2 years. The main issue comes with also trying to pull data from different time points since the beginning time is different. For instance, income for years 0-2 (exclusive) for observation 1 would come from income14, but income for year 0-2 for observation would come from income18. In the end, I'd like my data to look something like this:

```
id  st.time end.time    event2  censor  inc

1   0       2           0       0       8
1   2       4           0       0       10
1   4       6           1       0       13
2   0       2           0       1       24
```

Thus, I'm trying to think of the best way to code to account for pulling the data from different points in time since the beginning reference time is not constant across observations.

Comment: So, time to event 2 is what we want to split in chunks. So for observation 1, there was six years between t_0 and t_1. The problem is with time varying covariates, I need to now split observation 1 among those 6 years and calculate the risk in each of those periods, from 14-16, 1-18, and 18-20.

Comment: Since this comes from panel data, the data comes biannually.

Comment: can you please update the post with those info.  For a person reading this, may have those kind of doubts. thanks

Comment: It's hard to imagine this was the original data organization. Looks like someone aggregated the data from a series of individual surveys. It would probably be easier to go back to the origianl data and work from there.